# ObjectMapper - Parse String to Object

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I try to parse my String to Object using `ObjectMapper.readValue(...)`

I have `String line = {"jobID":"123","clientID":"555","userID":"444"}` and class:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class JSon{  

    private String jobID;
    private String clientID;
    private String userID;

}
```

When I try to parse my String to Object `new ObjectMapper().readValue(line, JSon.class)`, I got exception:

> Method threw
> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException'
> exception. Root name 'jobID' does not match expected ('JSon') for type
> [simple type, class JSon].

How can it possible to solve that problem?

**UPDATE:** I added configure to my ObjectMapper and it resolved my problem

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)
```

Comment: Not sure about the error message you've posted, but you'll probably need `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` on `JSon`, because otherwise Jackson doesn't have a default constructor (because of builder)

Comment: You can use `@JsonProperty("jobID")` etc, to specify fields

Comment: @Max, no, thank you. But that solution doesn't work

Comment: As @ernest_k said, try to add `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`

Comment: @George Lvov, I did it, but it didn't help me. ObjectMapper() wait some root element ( {"MqJson": {"jobID":"123","clientID":"555","userID":"444"}} ), but I don't have it. How can I ignore root element?